# nginx redirect subdomain to a folder

Tags: web-server, nginx, subdomain, rewrite

In Nginx, I would like to redirect my subdomain.domain.com to domain.com/sub/ .how do I do that ?
I would like to use the existing sites config file for domain.com instead of creating a new one.

the config file I have is  (how do I add to this)

======

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name www.domain.com domain.com  *.domain.com;
access_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
error_log /srv/www/domain.com/logs/error.log;

location / {
    root   /srv/www/domain.com/public_html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

location /phpmyadmin {
      root /usr/share;
      index index.php;
    }

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/www/domain.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

=========

Answer (score 3):

Sorry Mike, your if statement solution is a bad idea... refer to the Nginx [pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) wiki page for why (in this case nginx will evaluate the directive for every request, which is inefficient)...

Add another server block above the one you have containing this:

```
server {
   server_name subdomain.domain.com;
   rewrite ^ $scheme://domain.org/subdomain$request_uri redirect;
}
```

and magic will be done...

Answer (score 0):

This would go in your server block. This is untested but should work or give you an idea

```
if ($host ~* "^(.*)\.domain\.com$"){
  set $subd $1;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$subd permanent;
  break;
}
```